# Try to use opacity in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, opacity

I'm trying to use `opacity` in my website, but it isn't working very well in IE8. My code is as following:

```
filter:alpha(opacity=80);
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
```

When I change the values, the resulting output is always the same.

Edit: Thanks for give me a other question with similar problem...but I have a layout and the opacity property it's applied to layout.

Comment: Is that all the code for your element? If so, then you might be suffering from IE8's [hasLayout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) issue.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/ check this out

Comment: @box86rowh haha i just answered that ;)

Comment: It works normally for me in IE8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This are all the css codes for opacity:

```
.classname {
  /* IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";

  /* IE 5-7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);

  /* Netscape */
  -moz-opacity: 0.8;

  /* Safari 1.x */
  -khtml-opacity: 0.8;

  /* Good browsers */
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Try to add all of these and it most likely works

Comment: I don't know for why but this code (without -khtml) works now.....Thanks!

Comment: okay strange, glad it helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

To support IE8+ transparency you only need the following:

```
.transparent {
    zoom: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/